# DataGridTemplateColumn с вложенным ComboBox не срабатывает команда

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть датагрид со столбцом, состоящим из комбобокса :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Change Status" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox>
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeStatus}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Received" IsSelected="True"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="InWork"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Closed"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Complited"/>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

При смене значения `SelectionChanged` в боксе должна сработать команда :

```
public RelayCommand ChangeStatus
    {

        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(()=> 
            {
               MessageBox.Show//

            });
        }

     }
```

Не срабатывает. Но если я просто сделаю комбобокс, отдельно от грида то  команда выполниться. Подскажите Как исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените `Binding` в `EventTrigger` c:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeStatus}"/>
```

на:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.ChangeStatus}" />
```

и будет вам счастье )

Comment: Работает. Спасибо! Не могли бы вы пояснить написанное? Если мне нужно передать выбранное значение?

Comment: В данном случае мы делаем следующее: от колонки, которая содержит `ComboBox`  идем вверх по дереву до тех пор пока не встретим элемент типа `DataGrid`. Как только данный элемент найден, мы обращаемся к его свойству `DataContext`, который будет содержать объект вашей `ViewModel`, и указываем команду `ChangeStatus` в этой `ViewModel`.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под: `Если мне нужно передать выбранное значение?` Вы хотите узнать элемент, который был выбран в `ComboBox`?

Comment: да. узнать какое значение выбрано в боксе.

Comment: @Сергей у 1) `InvokeCommandAction` укажите `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=SelectedItem}"` 2) Измените тип команды `ChangeStatus` на `RelayCommand<object>`, тот параметр который будет приходить в обработчик команды и будет являться выбранным элементом. Но на самом деле, такой способ работы я бы вам не рекомендовал. Лучше избавиться от этих `InvokeCommandAction` и пересмотреть структуру вашей `ViewModel`, которая привязывается к `DataGrid`.